# Upload email attachments to some cloud instead of saving as base64 in the database

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I'm here because I found this issue in the Oro Forum and since doesn't have new answers I'm opening the topic here too:

The problem with Oro CRM is that it upload the Email Attachments to the Database as base64 in the table `oro_email_attachment_content`. I don't understand why it was decided that way but it is problematic since it leads to huge tables. In my case that single table is like 400 GB in size.

For other type of attachments the same system uses the `knp_gaufrette`, why aren't you using the same for the email attachments?

The original question is from 2016 and some of the answers say that :

> probably get some priority in our next release

Is this being developed or there is a way o configuration that I missed to be able to move this files to AWS for example?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, there is on way to move these files to some external storage, but you can configure the sync to not download attachments at all or skip downloading large attachments.
There are two corresponding options for this:

- Enable Attachment Sync
- Maximum Sync Attachment Size

For more details see the documentation:
https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/configuration/system/general-setup/global-email/#configure-email-settings

Comment: So aren't you guys working on that like the Forum post said? I know that we can avoid sync to not download attachments or avoid larger ones but is not like we don't need the attachments, we do, but we don't want to have it in DB because it's not good for scalability or performance.

Comment: "aren't you guys working on that like the Forum post said." - as far as I see there are no plans to work on this feature anytime soon. Feel free to contribute.